# Firestore unit testing problem: Expected type 'DocumentReference', but it was: a custom Firestore object

Tags: javascript, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I want to run unit tests for firestore. I have the following code:

```
import { getDoc, setDoc } from "@firebase/firestore";
import {
  assertFails,
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeTestEnvironment,
  RulesTestEnvironment,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing"

describe('Creating a user', () => {
  let alice;
  let anon;
  let testEnv;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
      projectId: "PROJECT_ID"
    })
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice", { user_id: "1" });
    anon = testEnv.unauthenticatedContext();
  });

  test('alice can create a user', async () => {
    await assertSucceeds(setDoc(alice.firestore(), '/users/alice'), { "name": "alice" });
  })
});
```

This is according to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) where they suggest this sample code:

```
// Assuming a Firestore app and the Firestore emulator for this example
import { setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice", { … });
// Use the Firestore instance associated with this context
await assertSucceeds(setDoc(alice.firestore(), '/users/alice'), { ... });
```

However when I run the this, I get the following error:

> FirebaseError: Expected type 'DocumentReference', but it was: a custom Firestore object

At this line: `await assertSucceeds(setDoc(alice.firestore(), '/users/alice'), { "name": "alice" });`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have looked through the official documentation, but it is not clear to me why this isn't working.

npm dependencies:

```
├── @babel/cli@7.21.0
├── @babel/core@7.21.3
├── @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs@7.21.2
├── @babel/preset-env@7.20.2
├── @firebase/rules-unit-testing@2.0.7
├── firebase@9.18.0
└── jest@29.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I cant find the example you mention in the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) you provide.

> This is according to the official documentation where they suggest this sample code:

`setDoc` takes a `DocumentReference` as [first argument](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#setdoc) just what the exception you get is saying.